# curl_exec() returned data and the status code returned

Tags: php, curl

I'm just wondering, when using `cURL` and you get the results of the cURL operation via:

```
$ch = curl_init('www.example.com');
.......
$response = curl_exec($ch);
```

... and then get the status code via:

```
$response_code = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
```

If the status code returned to `$response_code` is anything BUT `200` does that mean that `curl_exec` will always return false?

Comment: Is this code is what exactly which you are using, and please show your code which is in between `curl_init` and `curl_exec`

Comment: No it doesn't, for instance if you get an `301` then you will still get a valid response.

Comment: @BhaveshGangani The code isn't really relevant which is why I have left it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Curl_exec wont return false if the status code returned is even 200.
```

As @krister mentioned you will get get a value response(returns the result) if the status code is even `301`.